# call function in in yii CGridView

Tags: yii

I am newbie to yii, I am calling a function in CGridView to display value in the column. But I was unable to get that value for other columns as well. I am calling same function three times (TblPaid::model()->alreadyPaidUpto()). I want to call the function once and use the value again. This is the extract of CGridView Columns. Can someone pl. give me a hint?

```
            array('name'=>'Paid upto this Date',
            'value'=>'number_format((TblPaid::model()->alreadyPaidUpto($data->id, $this->grid->extraparam)),2)','htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: right'),
            ),

            array('name'=>'Balance',
            'value'=>'number_format($data->amount-(TblPaid::model()->alreadyPaidUpto($data->id, $this->grid->extraparam)),2)','htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: right'),
            ),

            array(
                    'header'=>'Running Balance',
                    'class'=>'RunningTotalColumn',
                    'value'=>'$data->amount-(TblPaid::model()->alreadyPaidUpto($data->id, $this->grid->extraparam))',
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: right'),
            ),
```

Comment: Have you tried [*memoizing*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611196/real-world-example-of-memoization-in-javascript) the results of `alreadyPaidUpto`? That example shows the idea in JS, you can of course use the same concept in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First, be looking at the way you are calling this method, its probably wiser to declare it as `static` method eg:

```
public static function alreadyPaidUpto($arg1, $arg2) {}
```

But for example you could do it a method of your `$data` model (but I don't know the case because there isn't much code here). Eg `public function isAlreadyPaidUpTo($date)` and use it like this `$data->isAlreadyPaidUpTo($when);`

Then you could cache the value in the method:

```
public function isAlreadyPaidUpTo($date) {
    static $result = null;
    if ($result === null) {
        $result = ? // query db, etc
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If you show some REAL code, I might be able to be more helpful.

Comment: <?php   $dateReport=$_GET['dateReport'];
        $category=$_GET['category'];
        $officeID=$_GET['officeID'];
?>